# Multiple Web Part JavaScript Dependency

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-parts

Say I have a portal using 4 custom web parts - there about four different external javascript files that have (appropriately namespaced) common functions and properties to be shared with all 4 web parts.

What is the best practice for making sure that all web parts have access to those javascripts?  Do I include each of the four javascripts in the assembly of each web part?

Or do I make a 5th web part that solely exists for the requirement of including those javascripts?

Answer (score 0):

google requirejs and forever after be thankful that someone wrote this.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to web part development, or my question in general.